# link a archivos alojados en carpetas compartidas

Tags: html, href, enlace

Estoy tratando de colocar un link html (href) en mi formulario a archivos que se encuentran en carpetas compartidas en un servidor windows, mi aplicación está alojada en ubuntu.

```html
<td style="text-align:center;"><a href="file://fs1/Boletas%20Cyber/vtex-00-967020770393-01-6684064.pdf">file://fs1/Boletas%20Cyber/vtex-00-967020770393-01-6684064.pdf</a></td>
```

Pero me da error en el navegador:

Not allowed to load local resource: file://fs1/Boletas%20Cyber/vtex-00-967021309216-01-6684056.pdf

Estuve buscando si se podía resolver creando un link simbólico desde ubuntu a mi carpeta compartida, pero no se si esto resuelve mi problema (que tampoco se como crear el link simbólico)

Esto tiene solución? o solamente lo dejo como lo tengo ahora, mostrar la ruta y que el usuario la copie y la acceda desde otra ventana.